# How do I save a schema definition XSD file from Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, xml, xsd

Excel 2016 can internally create an XML schema definition imported from an XML data file.  It appears in the Excel "XML source" panel, listing the XML element hierarchy, which one can then map to columns or cells in the Excel worksheet.  One can add/edit data and then save the data as an XML file.

What I cannot figure out, for the life of me, is how to save just the schema definition (.xsd) file from Excel (***NOT*** the data XML file, just the schema definition XSD file) or, alternatively, ***BOTH*** the XML data file ***AND THE XSD SCHEMA FILE*** as two separate files.

What am I missing?

If this has been asked and answered before, please post a link to the earlier duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has the option to export the schema. However, there are many cases where it will not function.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-xml-data-0b21f51b-56d6-48f0-83d9-a89637cd4360#Common%20issues%20with%20exporting%20XML%20data

I did find a workaround. If you open the excel file as an archive with 7-zip or similar tool it contains a file called xmlMaps.xml.
The file contains all the xml maps for the document. Use a text editor to save each schema in a separate xsd file.